# Error Calling WebService with Attachment with Axis

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, ioexception

I get the below error when I attach an Octet Stream and call a WebService using a client created by Apache Axis

```
java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.apache.axis.attachments.OctetStream in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@c7b00c.

  Any suggestion on how I should proceed with the fix ?
```

Regards,

SKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by writing a custom OctetStreamSerializerFactory and OctetStreamDeSerilizerFactory. I added it to QName "Doc" in the SOAPStub class. 
The factory `implements SerializerFactory`. The getSerializer method returns an instance of `OctetStreamDataHandlerSerializer.